# FileSystemWatcher IncludeSubdirectories not working on network share

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I'm attempting to watch a network share for folders where a file is added to the share to indicate the upload is complete. I wanted to use a FileSystemWatcher to monitor that share and its subdirectories for that trigger file, as shown below.

```
FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(share, triggerFilePattern);
fsw.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
fsw.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
fsw.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);
fsw.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(OnError);
```

If a file is created at the root of the share, the event triggers. If a file is created within a subdirectory of the share, the event does *not* trigger, and I don't get an error either.

If I create a new FileSystemWatcher for that subdirectory, then I do receive an event when a file is created there. But, similar to the top level FileSystemWatcher, I won't get events for files created in any further subdirectories.

If I change the network share to a local directory for testing, it does work as expected.

Any ideas? Could I have set up some wonky network share setting that blocks recursive FileSystemWatcher checks? I can work around this, but it would be nice to not have to complicate the code.

Edit: I saw that I didn't have Full Control under Properties->Security tab, so I thought that could be it. But I was able to get normal desired behavior on a different share with the same visible permissions, so I'm back to not knowing why this specific share isn't working.

Edit2: At a coworker's suggestion, I added a Changed handler too. Doesn't make sense to me how a file can be changed without getting Created first, but... I'm getting Changed events on the share in question when creating files in a subdirectory. (And I'm still getting nothing when renaming them.) This solves my immediate problem, but I'm going to leave the question open in case someone's able to answer *why* that's happening.

Comment: Are the security permissions of the sub-directories the same as the security permissions of the root-directory?

Comment: The visible permissions in the Properties->Security tab are the same.

Comment: Have you tried setting 
fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true; 
?

Comment: What is the backing operating system? Is it a share exposed from Windows? This is usually a problem with bad SMB emulation, most commonly found with Synology NAS shares since DSM 5.2.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 private static FileSystemWatcher fw;
 static void Main(string[] args)
       {
            fw = new FileSystemWatcher(@"D:\Folder_Watch");
            fw.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            fw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess |
     NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
            fw.Created += fw_Created;
            fw.Changed += fw_Created;
            fw.Renamed += fw_Created;
            fw.Filter = "*.*";
            fw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false).WaitOne();        
        }

 static void fw_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                fw.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
                //Your Code
            }
            finally
            {
                fw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and **I solved it** by giving **write permission** to the shared network folder (it had only read permission so far). Shared folder is originally on **Linux** but I have it mounted on **Windows Server 2008 R2** where I'm running program with FileSystemWatcher.