# FileSystemWatcher not working even once except for root folder having 320K subdirectories

Tags: c#, windows-services, console-application, filesystemwatcher

I am using below code to monitor changes happening in a directory including subdirectories. Currently, I am running three different copies of this application and two of them are working fine. Application for which it is not working contains more than 320K subdirectories in it.

I tried to increase `InternalBufferSize` but nothing happens.
It is working at the root folder and not working for any of the subdirectories.

Also, 2 other copies of the same application monitoring different network paths on different geographical locations are working fine including subdirectories as well.

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
{
    Path = path,
    IncludeSubdirectories = true,
    Filter = "*.txt",
    NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite |
        NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
};
watcher.Created += Watcher_Created;
watcher.Changed += Watcher_Changed;
watcher.Deleted += Watcher_Deleted;
watcher.Renamed += Watcher_Renamed;
watcher.Error += Watcher_Error;
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

PS: Polling is not an option. It takes 3 days to scan entirely 320K directories.
The root-level folder has 2000 plus subdirectories and each subdirectory has up-to 8 levels of subfolders in it

**Edit-1:I have checked with the INFRA team and got to know that shared folders are on EMC Isilon NAS storage.**

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/38adb37d-bbfc-40d6-8b32-a5c1c7d8d4a3/are-there-any-limitations-of-filesystemwatcher-monitoring-a-unc-path-on-nas-server?forum=netfxbcl

Comment: The 320K subdirectories are all placed directly under the watched directory, or they form a deep hierarchy? In the second case, how may subdirectories are directly under the watched directory?

Comment: It's around 2k subdirectories at root level.

Comment: Have you checked if it's viable to instantiate one `FileSystemWatcher` per subdirectory at root level?

Comment: Btw pay attention to this advice from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher#events-and-buffer-sizes): *"Keep your event handling code as short as possible."* If you are doing anything time-consuming inside the event handlers, no matter how large is the `InternalBufferSize`, with that many subdirectories it's almost certain you're gonna lose notifications. Ideally you should do nothing more than pushing a message to a queue, for further processing by another workflow.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias There are no events getting triggered when any changes are made to subdirectories. Events are simply dumping the received information into SQLite databse table. Same code is working fine for 2 other folders which have around 100k folders in entire hierarchy

Comment: @TheodorZoulias In case I initialize one FileSystemWatcher per subdirectory at root level, same issue happens for the subdirectories at next level. This change fixes only for current level.

Comment: Could you provide more info about the affected system? Operating system version, .NET Framework/.NET Core version, storage hardware model etc. It may help someone more knowledgeable than me to identify the possible source of the problem.

Comment: You could also try targeting a smaller directory in the same system, to rule out the possibility that the specific system does not honor the `IncludeSubdirectories = true` configuration.

Comment: Thanks @TheodorZoulias. I have tried the same in smaller directory which has just 3 subdirectories in it. Same behaviour, working for root level and not for subdirectories

Comment: I have deployed 3 copies of the same application developed in .net core 3.1 on same machine running windows 10. Each copy is monitoring to different folders. Two of them are working fine except one.

Comment: So it seems that the number of subdirectories is irrelevant to the problem. What seems relevant is that 3 copies of the same application are running on the same machine. Could you experiment more based on that? Does the order that you start the three processes makes any difference, regarding which process will be affected by the problem? What about more than three processes, like four or five? Does the number of healthy or unhealthy processes goes up? What if each process watches a directory located in a different physical storage, mounted on the same machine?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias thanks for your consistent efforts. 2 other copies of the same application monitoring different network paths on different geographical locations. I have tried to change the order of the execution of the 3 applications and it doesn't have any issues in working 2 applications and no positive results for the failing one.

Comment: So the fact that two other copies of the app are running concurrently seems to be irrelevant too. My current guess is that the problem is related with the specific network path that is monitored.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I think so. There seems be no coding issues as it is working fine for other 2 network paths. I am not able to figure out what could be changed in infrastructure to get it working

Comment: Here is another one having the same problem: [FileSystemWatcher IncludeSubdirectories not working on network share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835090/filesystemwatcher-includesubdirectories-not-working-on-network-share). You may need to check the permissions you have on that network path.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I tried adding/deleting files from network drive and I was able to do so. That means, I have write permissions too. Anyways thanks a lot, I will look into from this angle as well :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of executing the event handlers synchronously, it may help to offload them to the `ThreadPool`. This will minimize the risk of overflowing the internal buffer of the `FileSystemWatcher`. The `Offload` method below could be used for this purpose:

```
public static FileSystemEventHandler Offload(FileSystemEventHandler handler)
{
    return (s, e) => ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => handler(s, e));
}
```

Usage example:

```
var fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(path);
fsw.Created += Offload((s, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Created: {e.Name}");
});
```

This is not intended as an efficient solution, but just as an easy fix to the buffer-overflow problem (assuming that it's the cause for the issues you are observing).

Comment: Problem I am facing is if I add a file in root directory even after one day, events are triggered but if I add/delete/rename/change file in any of the immediate/lower subdirectories, no events are triggered.