# FileSystemWatcher not raising an event in case of more than 8 files or folders delete at a time in long length path (>243)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, filesystemwatcher

Whenever we tried to delete more than 8 files at a time in long length path (>243 characters), the `FileSystemWatcher` processing for one `Deleted` event and after that not processing the other remaining deleted files.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-6.0)? It states: "If there are many changes in a short time, the buffer can overflow. This causes the component to lose track of changes in the directory, and it will only provide blanket notification". That sounds like the problem you are seeing. It also suggests that this may be resolved by increasing the value of the `InternalBufferSize` property. Have you tried this? (Note that the buffer comes from unpaged memory, so it also advises you keep the buffer as small as possible).

Comment: Could you try reducing to a minimum the code inside the `Deleted` event handler, and see if the problem still exists? You could also experiment with the `Offload` method found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66258633/filesystemwatcher-not-working-even-once-except-for-root-folder-having-320k-subdi/66293976#66293976) answer.